# How to make a CSV file from a number of lists?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to make a csv file using the lists

```
['2005-04-18', '2005-04-19', '2005-04-20']

['1', '1', '1']

['0.7683', '0.766664', '0.764696']

['1.380162', '1.373308', '1.358544']
```

with the dates in the first column and the corresponding values across the rows

i already have

```
with open((os.path.join('data','hist', 'rates-'+date1+' to ' +date2+ '.csv')), 'wt') as my_csv:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(my_csv, lineterminator='\n')
    csv_writer.writerow(["Date",curr1, curr2, curr3])
```

which gives me the file with the headers. How can I finish this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You evidently know how to write a list to a CSV file, so what's tripping you up?

Comment: Side note: instead of string concatenation, people normally use the (generally) faster and more legible `"rates-{} to {}.csv".format(date1, date2)`.

Comment: You could use zip(): https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a loop to process the elements of the arrays that you have.

```
a = ['2005-04-18', '2005-04-19', '2005-04-20']
b = ['1', '1', '1']
c = ['0.7683', '0.766664', '0.764696']
d = ['1.380162', '1.373308', '1.358544']
```

You can use `zip` to create tuples from the lists and write those:

```
for row in zip(a, b, c, d):
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Or you can just youse string formatting and print it into the file yourself (without using csv_writer):

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    csv_writer.writerow('{}, {}, {}, {}'
        .format(a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i]))
```