# Make a csv file from database column

Tags: python, csv

So Im working with Jupyter and `SELECT`ed some Data from a `table` which is structured as a tulp like so: `[(5, 2, 11, 5), (11, 1, 4, 8), (12, 2, 11, 2),...]`. I would like to convert it into a csv file and of course you could write a function to remove the brackets etc. but isn't there a "offical" way? 
No universal converter like `pytz` for `python time`
or something similar?

I found this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030363/how-to-make-a-csv-file-from-a-number-of-lists), which suggests to iterate over single lines with a `for loop` and I would like to know if that really is the best way to do it.

Comment: `pandas`........ It's a really useful tool for working with data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ There is no need to use pandas where a humble CSV writer suffices.

Comment: @DYZ OP asked for the "best way" (sure, this is subjective). `pandas` works nicely for large data. Also, what if each sublist contains a column instead of a row? Transposition with `zip` will be terribly slow. Just throwing this out there, since that was what OP wanted to know about.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I use `pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from something;", conn)` currently....

Comment: @Marla Well... just use `df.to_csv(...)` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is already ready to be written to a CSV file. Create a CSV writer and tell it to write all rows at once:

```
import csv
with open("foo.csv", "w") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    w.writerows(your_data)
```

EDIT: If the data is already in a Pandas DataFrame, them COLDSPEED is right and `df.to_csv(...)` is the most convenient way to save it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Yup, saw that :) Trying to direct OP to it.